# How can I list the available objects to inject in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

Is there a way to programatically list all available beans in the grails spring injection context?  In guice I was able to do this by looking up the bindings configured in the injector.

Answer (score 24):

I use this:

```
ctx.beanDefinitionNames.sort().each { println it }
```

where `ctx` is the Spring `ApplicationContext`. You can get that in a controller/service/etc. with

```
def grailsApplication
...
def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
```

Given all of the bean names, you can inspect individual ones with

```
def bean = ctx.getBean(name)
```